# Sets - Inclusion Exclusion Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So here's the question:

Consider the following information regarding three sets A, B, and C all of which are subsets of a set U. If n(S) denotes the number of members of S, suppose that n(A) = 14, n(B) = 10, N(A U B U C) = 24 and n(A Intersect B) = 6. Which ones are true considering the following assertions:

1. C has at most 24 members
2. C has at least 6 members
3. A U B has exactly 18 members.

Here's my reasoning and my answers: 1 and 2 are false because C can't have at most 24 members, since the union of A and B already nets you 24. 2 can't be true either because then the union of A, B, and C would be 28. 3 is true because since the intersection of A and B is 6, that means there are 6 elements A and B have in common and when you perform the union you ignore duplicates. So you would get 24 but then you would have to subtract 6 in order to get 18.

Am I correct or is there something off with my reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer and argument for 3) is correct.  One could give the justification more formally by writing
$$n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cap B).$$
We know all the numbers on the right-hand side, so we know $n(A\cup B)$. But in my opinion the informal justification you gave is enough.

For 1), certainly $C$ can have at most $24$ members, since $A\cup B\cup C$ has $24$ members, and $C\subseteq A\cup B\cup C$.

And $C$ does have at least $6$ members. For by 3), $A\cup B$ has $18$ members. Since $A\cup B\cup C$ has $24$ members, $C$ must provide at least $6$ members. Note that $C$ and $A\cup B$ could overlap. Nothing in the statement of the problem describes the amount of overlap, so altogether $C$ could have anywhere from $6$ to $6+18$ members.

Comment: So, every assertion is true?

Comment: How can C have up to 24 members if the union of A and B is 18?

Comment: To be technical, to answer 1) you only need to show that $C$ cannot have more than $24$ members. But in fact it can have $24$. We have a class of $24$ students. $A$ is the set of students with brown hair. $B$ is the set with blue eyes. And $C$ is the set of all students. If there are $14$ with brown hair, $10$ with blue eyes, and $6$ with both, then all conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Ah, I see. Got it.